# What is the short story about your soul being trapped in an alien creature

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story as the first story in an anthology but can't recall anything about the name or author.

Premise is narrator is called to a mountain observatory at night / in the rain where their colleague / mentor has something to share with them.  The mentor has proof that when you die, your soul leaves the body and heads into space.  You can track it and they tune the machine to some which is basically just the person repeating their name over and over.  I think Hitler is name dropped as one they find.

The horror though is that the destination for the soul is a planet with an utter alien creature where it's bound to it for eternity as the machine hears the soul screaming in terror at the alienness of it.

I'm pretty sure mentor dies/suicides at the end and off goes their soul.

Comment: This feels like a _before the golden age_ story. A _cosmic horror_ story as Clark Ashton Smith might have written (though I'm pretty certain the story is not one of his). Can you remember whether it was an anthology of old stories?

Comment: I really can't, I was reading a lot of different things.  For awhile I thought it was part of a James Tiptree Jr collection but when I went looking realized that was just a fevered dream.  I remember clearly it was the first story and it set the tone for the book but recall none of the others.  In writing it I thought of HP Lovecraft but the Hitler namedrop is a strong memory of the story.

Comment: @DougW One of the later books of  Farmer's _Riverworld_ series has soul tracking and Hermann Göring, but it wasn't a crazy scientist's gadget story.